# How to evaluate power, root , factorial functions in java using JEval library?

Tags: java, math, calculator

I am not getting how to perform these operations using JEval library in Java

```
           String b = "8!"; // Not working
           String a = "2^2"; // Not Working

          Evaluator mEvaluator = new Evaluator();
    try {
        String r2 = mEvaluator.evaluate(b);

    } catch (EvaluationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and i don't know how to get root in string ?

Comment: I assume that the root is either "sqrt(x)" for square roots or "root(x, y)" for the yth root of x. You should check out JEval's documentation for a definite answer.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/docs/api/index.html). Neither factorial nor power are supported. You'll have to use the specific classes for that.

Comment: 8! is eight factorial: 8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1. It's a useful operator in probability/statistics, among other things. But as Heuster said, it may not be supported in JEval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a class `Sqrt` in `JEval`. See [this](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/docs/api/net/sourceforge/jeval/function/math/Sqrt.html).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation. Factorial is not supported.

For **power** you can use

```
net.sourceforge.jeval.function.math.Pow
```

and for **Root** you can use

```
net.sourceforge.jeval.function.math.Sqrt
```